# Assigning individuals to populations

Tags: r

I am trying to group 39 plant samples into 3 populations based on species, EWM, HWM, and NWM, in polysat.

The tutorial uses this code to group data into 3 populations, with 100 samples in each.

> PopNames(simgen) <- c("PopA", "PopB", "PopC")
>
> PopInfo(simgen) <- rep(1:3, each = 100)

Each of my populations contains a different number of samples (EWM=17, HWM=6, NWM=16), so this code isn't quite what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem and instead of: `PopInfo(simgen) <- rep(1:3, each = 100)`, you can use: `PopInfo(simgen) <- rep(1:3, c(17,6,16))`.
Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for responding.  I ran this code and it added samples to populations alphabetically.  You have to input data assorted by locus, right, (ie, the order of the txt document is samples 1-10 with locus 1, samples 1-10 with locus 2, etc)?  Instead of ordering them by sample, (ie, sample 1 with locus 1-3, sample 2 with locus 1-3, etc).

Comment: I used the .txt file mentioned in the [official tutorial of Polysat - page 9 - first paragraph](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/polysat/vignettes/polysattutorial.pdf) as template for mine and, as you mentioned, you need to arrange your samples by marker  ( marker 1 - sample1, sample2, sample3; marker 2 - sample1, sample2, sample3).

Answer (score 0):

Just in case anyone else is searching, I did figure this out yesterday:

When you prepare your excel sheet, sort by marker, then species/population, then by sample name.  Then you can use the < PopInfo(simgen) <- rep(1:3, c(17,6,16)) > code to sort into populations.

I'm not sure how to do this if you don't already know the populations, but hopefully this will help someone out!